# ¿Cómo puedo redirigir a un usuario admin logueado a diferentes páginas basado en datos de la sesión en PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

**mercaderia.php**

```
include('conexion.php');
include('includes/header2.php');
require('altalogin.php');
//uso de la funcion verificar_usuario()
if (verificar_usuario()){
//si el usuario es verificado puede acceder al contenido permitido a el
include('formMercaderia.php');
}else{
//si el usuario no es verificado volvera al formulario de ingreso
echo "<script language='javascript'>";
echo "alert('Debe loguearse primero')";
echo "</script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "window.location = 'index.php'";
echo "</script>";
exit();
}
?>

include('includes/footer2.php');
```

[image: formulario de mercaderia en php]
Estoy armando un pequeño proyecto de estudio en `PHP`, `MySQL`, `HTML5`, `bootstrap` y algo de `Ajax` para buscador.

El sistema es página principal para loguearse como administrador, redirige a alta de mercadería que tiene dos contenedores uno el formulario de alta hacia la base de datos y el otro tiene una tablet donde recupera y muestra los datos, incluye un buscador por nombre y apellido usando `Ajax` con `jquery`.

Header y footer con logout usando sesiones, el error viene dado en el alta del formulario que se envía por post hacia un validador y se refresca en la misma página mostrando los datos en el contenedor derecho.

Cuando se envía los datos , muestra un mensaje que el usuario debe iniciar sesión, se están incluyendo una `conexion.php` que contiene `session_start();` cuando válida y recibe las variables del formulario, y no encuentro el error.
Desde ya gracias, si alguno me puede indicar el error o buenas prácticas de armado. 
Dejo el link:

[mercaderia 2.0](https://github.com/carlosdelviento/Ejercicios_Crud_PHP/tree/master/altamercaderia/mercaderia2.0)

Comment: Deberías intentar agregar una parte del código para poderte ayudar, que nos pases todo el proyecto es más complicado.

Comment: ahi he agregado lo que seria mercaderia.php, por que codigo php no se puede poner por aqui

Comment: @CarlosBarbieri Evita poner información sensible en las publicaciones. Has puesto tu usuario/contraseña en un lugar público. Dependiendo del nivel de la cuenta, deberías tratar eso como un problema grave de seguridad y cambiar la contraseña para esa cuenta lo antes posible.

Comment: Aparte del comentario anterior, por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir el código relevante en modo texto. Añadir el código como imágenes presenta problemas de accesibilidad (el código no se puede leer) y hace más difícil ayudarte (no podemos copiar/ejecutar el código para probarlo). Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] y edita la pregunta para añadir más información y poner el código en modo texto. Saludos.

Comment: gracias, lo corregí